# AI-possessed Pawn flies off at incredibly high speed immediately after hitting play (UE4)

Tags: physics, unreal-4

I have a very simple pawn with a Sphere Collision and a child Static Mesh. This pawn is set to be possessed by an AI Controller on spawn and the AI Controller basically sets up the blackboard and runs the behaviour tree. The behaviour tree is set to do nothing. As soon as I hit play in the editor, the pawn falls to the floor and bounces off at speeds almost too fast to see and quickly flies out of the edges of the worldmap and gets deleted.

[alt text](https://answers.unrealengine.com/storage/temp/234353-screen-shot-2018-03-18-at-64231-pm.png)

In the picture above, the blurred blue thing is the object thats rocketing away.

I've been stuck on this for a very long time, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried turning off the collision for the static mesh?  It could be conflicting with the Sphere Collision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a friend and Stephan Mar, I figured out that the collision setup for the static mesh was touching the sphere collision, causing it to infinitely launch itself away. To fix it, I got rid of the Sphere Collision Component and created custom Physics Asset for the static mesh.

Comment: Okay, marked. I might come back to this and add more details if it turns out people need that. (: